# Error pulling a remote repository from Jenkins to ubuntu directory

Tags: jenkins, github, ubuntu-16.04

this is my configuration script on Jenkins

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "Switching to project docroot."
cd /var/www/html/testdrupal.localhost/public_html
echo ""
echo "Pulling down the latest code."
git pull origin master
echo ""
echo "Clearing drush caches."
drush cache-clear drush
echo ""
echo "Running database updates."
drush updb -y
echo ""
echo "Importing configuration."
drush config-import -y
echo ""
echo "Clearing caches."
drush cr
echo ""
echo "Deployment complete."
```

However, the task execution is not successful due to this error:

```
Pulling down the latest code.
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

my git repository is as follows:  https://github.com/myId/drupaltest

Furthermore, this is the content of the .git folder inside the docroot:

```
drwxrwxrwx  7 root    root    4096 Sep 19 11:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root    4096 Sep 19 10:45 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root    root    4096 Sep 19 10:44 branches
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      92 Sep 19 10:44 config
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      73 Sep 19 10:44 description
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jenkins jenkins   81 Sep 19 11:11 FETCH_HEAD
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      23 Sep 19 10:44 HEAD
drwxrwxrwx  2 root    root    4096 Sep 19 10:44 hooks
drwxrwxrwx  2 root    root    4096 Sep 19 10:44 info
drwxrwxrwx 11 root    root    4096 Sep 19 11:11 objects
drwxrwxrwx  4 root    root    4096 Sep 19 10:44 refs
```

**EDIT**

I have updated the docroot:

```
cd /var/www/html/testdrupal.localhost/public_html/drupaltest
```

and now the error has changed:

```
error: can not open .git / FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

Just set the right permissions to the .git folder?

Comment: did you `git clone` before  `git pull` in the script ?

Comment: I edited the post